# PlaySound() keeps playing my .wav after WM_DESTROY and a DrawText Issue

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am experimenting on Windows 7 64 bit OS with win32 API.When i run my Program on debug mode my window appears but i have 2 bugs. Firt things first here is my api code modified from Charles Petzold book Ch3:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<mmsystem.h>





LRESULT CALLBACK HandleMyWindowsClassMessages(HWND WindowHandle, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPreviousInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{

    WNDCLASSEX MyWindowsClass;
    static wchar_t szMyWindowsClassName[] = TEXT("The Name of My Window Class");
    static wchar_t szAppName[] = TEXT("AppName");
    HWND myWindowHandle;
    MSG msg;

    MyWindowsClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    MyWindowsClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    MyWindowsClass.lpfnWndProc = HandleMyWindowsClassMessages;
    MyWindowsClass.lpszClassName = szMyWindowsClassName;
    MyWindowsClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    MyWindowsClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    MyWindowsClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    MyWindowsClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    MyWindowsClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    MyWindowsClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD);
    MyWindowsClass.hIconSm = NULL;
    MyWindowsClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&MyWindowsClass))
    {
        MessageBoxEx(0, TEXT("This Programm Requires WINNT!"), szMyWindowsClassName, MB_ICONERROR, 0);
        return(0);
    }

    myWindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        szMyWindowsClassName,
        szAppName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(myWindowHandle, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(myWindowHandle);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, myWindowHandle, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HandleMyWindowsClassMessages(HWND WindowHandle, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //wchar_t szGreeting[] = TEXT("Heeeey");
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;


    switch (Message)
    {

        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\mp3\\aywy._&_EphRem_-_Adderall.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            return(0);
        } break;

        case  WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(WindowHandle, &ps);
            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello Win 7!!!"), -1, &ps.rcPaint, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            //TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, szGreeting, (int)wcslen(szGreeting));
            EndPaint(WindowHandle, &ps);
            return(0);
        }break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return(0);
        }break;

    }

    return(DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Bug1:PlaySound keeps playing the wav even when i have closed-destroyed the Window.When I used the original example with plain WNDCLASS the bug dissapeared!
So I must be doing something wrong using WNDCLASSEX ???.
Also in this bug to end execution of debbuging I have to press `Shift+F5`.

Bug2:TextOut vs DrawText
Info:I have only 1 screen.I program on my laptop.
When I use drawText and the text in my window goes out of my desktop screen borders the text just doesnt update correclty.
When I use TextOut the bug dissapears!!!
Why???

Below i have some pitures ordered to explain this.

1. The Program starts in debug mode
   [image: Program start]
2. Moving the window out of Desktop borders(including the displayed text)
   [image]
3. Moving the window back inside my desktop area(the text has been mutated)
   [image: Window is back again]
4. Window is destroyed and sound will keep playing even when the wav ends.
   [image: Window Destroyed]

Any help in any of the 2 bugs would be greatly appreciated.

2nd version of my WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HandleMyWindowsClassMessages(HWND WindowHandle, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //wchar_t szGreeting[] = TEXT("Heeeey");
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rc;

    rc.left = 50; rc.top = 100; rc.right = 200; rc.bottom = 200;

    switch (Message)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\mp3\\aywy._&_EphRem_-_Adderall.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        return(0);
    } break;

    case  WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(WindowHandle, &ps);
        DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello Win 7!!!"), -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        //TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, szGreeting, (int)wcslen(szGreeting));
        EndPaint(WindowHandle, &ps);
        return(0);
    }break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PlaySound(NULL, NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return(0);
    }break;

    }

    return(DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Comment: What does your message pump look like?  Is it still the same as the first bit of code you posted?  You might try `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)` instead.  Since your window is destroyed you might be missing the `WM_QUIT` that would cause the loop to break.

Comment: Look in your code for `GetMessage` and replace `myWindowHandle` with `NULL`.

Comment: You are correct sir and I am blind and dizzy.Thank you.I deleted my last comment..felt like a facepalm in my face on a popular site :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Call `PlaySound( NULL, NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC)` before `PostQuitMessage` to stop the sound.
2. About `DrawText` - note that `BeginPaint` returns rectangle `rcPaint` for the region which needs redraw. If you are using it for start point of `DrawText`, the text will appear at different places. For example - when first created, the region will start at 0,0. Then you can move another window over DrawText application window and it can require repaint from point 80,100 to lower right corner. Try with absolute (client) coordinates, e.g. define `RECT rc` and set `rc.left = 50; rc.top = 100; rc.right = 200; rc.bottom = 200;` (always the same position).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.I tried the 1st answer and it is correct.I will try the 2nd anwer and will come back to accept the answer.Btw when i used `WNDCLASS` instead of `WINDCLASSEX` i didnt have to call `Playsound()` at `WM_DESTROY:`.Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Don't know what could be the reason. You can try again with `WNDCLASS`. Maybe you have changed other things and forget them... e.g. `SND_ASYNC` flag.

Comment: You are correct about using a steady RECT to display text .Thank you for clearing these windows procedures  more to me. A part of the bug remains though.Process wont terminate normally.I still need `Shift+F5 ` even though threads exit like in picture 4.I will modify my changes Wind Proc so u can see my code clearer.

Comment: I will check the answer anyway...I just want to give it sometime for the 3rd bug`Shift+F5`.Which i didnt properly ask :(